# Rails 5 nested attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Address and Customer model, want to create Address with associated Customer in 1 form. 'address_id' is primary key of Address table, foreign key of Customer table.

## address.rb

```
has_one :customer
accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
```

## customer.rb

```
belongs_to :address
```

## routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :customers, :addresses
end
```

## admin\addresses\new

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @address] do |a| %>
  <p>Customer</p>
    <%= a.fields_for @customer do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= c.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= c.select(:store_id, 1..2) %>
    <% end %>

  <p>Address</p>
    <%= a.text_field :phone %>
    <%= a.text_field :address %>
    <%= a.text_field :address2 %>
    <%= a.text_field :district %>
    <%= a.number_field :city_id %></td>
    <%= a.text_field :postal_code %>
<%= a.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## addresses_controller.rb

```
class Admin::AddressesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @address = Address.new
  @customer = Customer.new
end

def create
  @address = Address.new(address_params)
  if @address.save
    redirect_to(admin_customers_path)
  else
    render('new')
  end   
 end

private
  def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:address, :address2, :district, :city_id, :postal_code, :phone, 
     customer_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :store_id, :address_id])
  end
```

It is creating address, but returning 'Unpermitted parameter: customer' in rails server:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T49t....", 
"address"=>{"customer"=>{"first_name"=>"Aaron", "last_name"=>"Thomas", "store_id"=>"2"}, 
"phone"=>"4151101010", "address"=>"10 Test st", "address2"=>"", "district"=>"Soma", "city_id"=>"15", "postal_code"=>"94103"}, "commit"=>"Create Address"}
Unpermitted parameter: customer
  (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (8.9ms)  INSERT INTO `address` (`address`, `address2`, `district`, `city_id`, `postal_code`, `phone`) VALUES ('10 Test st', '', 'Soma', 15, '94103', '4151101010')
  (51.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/customers
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try changing `params.require(:address).permit(..., customer_attributes: [])` to `params.require(:address).permit(..., customer: [])` and see what happens?

Comment: Also - in your controller, try using: `@customer =  @address.build_customer` instead. In fact - try this one first and don't bother with the other one if this works... I think Rails is treating them as separate things because you haven't linked them together using `build_` and so Rails doesn't realise you want them as `customer_attributes` of the `address` model. If this fix works I'll turn it into an Answer :)

Comment: I tried `params.require(:address).permit(..., customer: [])`, returned: `Customer(#89657760) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#44084300)` in browser.

Comment: `@customer = @address.build_customer` saved address, but not saving customer as previously: `Unpermitted parameter: customer` in rails server.

Comment: If you are saving an array, [this blog post might help](http://jaketrent.com/post/permit-array-rails-strong-parameters/).